# railstutorial: I have create my first association (users & posts), but can access posts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org, ruby-on-rails-5

After creating an association between users and microposts, we are asked to show the first post in each user show method. Then I do that (in users controller.rb)

```
 def show
  @microposts = User.first.microposts.first
 end
```

In rails console the query give me back the correct result, but I can't get it in the browser. What am I doing wrong?

The current result is user info instead of first post.

Comment: how do output the result in the view?

Comment: As per your code , you will get the first micropost of the first user , it will give error if no micropost available for the first user. Your instance variable @micropost is accessible to your view, now what you want to achieve , mention the exact problem

Answer (score -1):

You are returning the first post of the first user, not the first post of the user you are showing. Try the following:

```
def show
  @user = User.find params[:id]
  @microposts = @user.microposts.first
end
```

However, it is not a good practice to use more instance variables than `@user` in your controller, I mean, the view should only have `@user` available instead of both `@user` and `@microposts`.

Comment: he has to find @user first, if not will be return not method microposts for nil class

Comment: You forgot brackets at 'User.find params[:id]'.. it should be '
      '@user = User.find(params[:id])'. It will throw out an error as of now.

Comment: With that:
     [code]@microposts = @user.microposts.first [/code]
should work, but it get me just de user info (profile)

Comment: @luissimo no it does not. It's the language's syntax and in ruby as long as your statement is clear you don't have to use parentheses